# How to add calculated fields in data extension in marketing cloud ?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I want to create a data extension contains where one fields contains concatenation value of 2-3 fields available in data extension. Is there any function or formula available for that ?

Comment: thanks, i'll do data processing before saving then.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do this using SQL. 
There is no inbuilt function per-se in the data extension/import to do this, so you will want to load your Data Extension (a) with your data, then use SQL to Concatenate your values and save the results into a Data Extension (b)

E.g.

```
SELECT (LastName + ', ' + FirstName) AS Name
```

Depending on your intended use, you could alternatively Concat values using Ampscript using the `Concat()` function and print the results